# Get PSU info through PMBus with lm-sensors

Tags: smbus, lm-sensors

I have a PSU and a motherboard, both from supermicro and both supporting PMBus (PSU: [datasheet](https://store.supermicro.com/us_en/pub/media/wysiwyg/productspecs/PWS-341P-1H/PWS-341P-1H_quick_spec.pdf), MB: [manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C606_602/MNL-1275.pdf))
After installing debian minimal and connecting all cables, I want to get a reading of the PSU sensors (more specifically, the input voltage).

I thought that lm-sensors should detect the PMBus sensors and display the values but it does not seem to work (`sudo sensors-detect` and `sensors` log below).

Now I don't know really where to look for an issue. This is a research project so there is no need for a clean solution, any help to get these value is appreciated.

`sudo sencors-detect

```
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# System: Supermicro X9DAi [0123456789]
# Kernel: 6.1.0-18-amd64 x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz (6/45/7)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): 
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               Yes
Found `Winbond W83627DHG-P/W83527HG Super IO Sensors'       
    (but not activated)
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): 
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): 
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel Patsburg (PCH)

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 9000 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Client found at address 0x2d
Handled by driver `nct7904' (already loaded), chip type `nct7904'
Client found at address 0x48
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM77'...                No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7410/ADT7420'...             No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7411'...                     No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP435'...                   No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM73'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM92'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM76'...                No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1023'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1043'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1053'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1063'...                               No
Client found at address 0x50
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Probing for `EDID EEPROM'...                                No

Next adapter: igb BB (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 

Next adapter: igb BB (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0000 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0001 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0002 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0005 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0006 (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0007 (i2c-8)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0008 (i2c-9)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0009 (i2c-10)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-aux-000a (i2c-11)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-aux-000b (i2c-12)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-aux-000c (i2c-13)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: nvkm-0000:81:00.0-aux-000d (i2c-14)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Driver `nct7904':
  * Bus `SMBus I801 adapter at 9000'
    Busdriver `i2c_i801', I2C address 0x2d
    Chip `nct7904' (confidence: 6)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
nct7904
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

`sensors`

```
hidpp_battery_0-hid-3-5
Adapter: HID adapter
in0:           4.19 V  

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A  

nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +33.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +69.8°C)
                       (crit = +79.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +35.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +32.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 5:     +38.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +61.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +60.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +55.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +54.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +61.0°C  
temp2:        +61.0°C
```

I tried to to detect the i2c address of the sensors by disconnecting the PMBus cable but could not see any different in the output of `i2cdetect -y 0`

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         08 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- 44 -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: 50 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- 61 -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 69 -- -- 6c -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

`sudo i2cdetect -l`

```
i2c-0   smbus       SMBus I801 adapter at 9000          SMBus adapter
i2c-1   i2c         igb BB                              I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c         igb BB                              I2C adapter
i2c-3   i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0000          I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0001          I2C adapter
i2c-5   i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0002          I2C adapter
i2c-6   i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0005          I2C adapter
i2c-7   i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0006          I2C adapter
i2c-8   i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0007          I2C adapter
i2c-9   i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0008          I2C adapter
i2c-10  i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-bus-0009          I2C adapter
i2c-11  i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-aux-000a          I2C adapter
i2c-12  i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-aux-000b          I2C adapter
i2c-13  i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-aux-000c          I2C adapter
i2c-14  i2c         nvkm-0000:81:00.0-aux-000d          I2C adapter
```

I am looking for a solution to programatically retrieve the PSU sensors values. Python or bash prefered but really any hacky solution will do. I can provide any log that would be relevant.

Comment: lm-sensors may not have an entry for your specific PSU and motherboard. You can create your own once you have the I2C bus and address worked out, or search https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors for similar ones to modify. What does `i2cdetect -l` say? Have you tried scanning other I2C buses? It's not a given that the motherboard SMBus/PMBus connector attaches to what Linux sees as I2C bus 0, to which sensitive components - CPU, PCH, DRAM etc. - are hard wired.

Comment: `i2cdetect -l` lists 14 interfaces but only the first one seems related to SMBUS/PMBus: `i2c-0 smbus      SMBus I801 adapter at 9000       SMBus adapter`. When detecting devices on this one nothing changes with the PMBus cable plugged in or not. on the other interfaces the listing is very slow and show no device detected.

Comment: Yes, igb bb seem to be network card I2C interfaces and nvkm-... come from the nouveau video driver. I could not find a detailed datasheet for that PSU to find out what its SMBus address is, or cable pinouts, although one would expect SuperMicro motherboard and PSU SMBus cables to be compatible. The only next steps I can suggest is to find the pinout and connect the PSU SMBus to a logic analyzer, controller or something that can communicate by I2C without possibility of I2C address clash, and try talking to it.